# How can I record ARSCNView without any UI element?

Tags: swift, xcode, augmented-reality, arkit, replaykit

I am trying to record the ARSCNView without the UI. In the way that user can see all the buttons and UI elements but when he is recording the screen, he records only the ARSCNView without the UI. 
Is it possible to do this using the ReplayKit?

I will be so happy to hear about your experiences.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SceneKitVideoRecorder](https://github.com/svtek/SceneKitVideoRecorder) library by `svtek` what is available through CocoaPods.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Although this works, it causes my frame rate drops. And the reason is the extra rendering function inside the library. What else can I try?